# Segmented Control returning wrong value?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func didSelect(_ segmentIndex: Int) {
    switch segmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        print ("1")

    case 1:
        // SHOWING THE PROFILE VIEW
        print ("2")

    default:
        print  ("break")
    }
}
```

I only have 2 tabs on the segment control, and whatever I click, it keeps printing "break". Why does that happen?

Comment: What is this action connected to? I don't know of any action that would take an `Int` as an argument.

Comment: @rmaddy the action is connected to a segment control button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of an `IBAction` **must** be the type of the connected UI element.

So you have to pass `UISegmentedControl` and switch on its `selectedSegmentIndex`

```
@IBAction func didSelect(_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch control.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        print ("1")

    case 1:
        // SHOWING THE PROFILE VIEW
        print ("2")

    default:
        print  ("break")
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: 

Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'UISegmentedControl'

Comment: You are switching on `control` rather than **`control.selectedSegmentIndex`**